# Mouse works but clicks are not registered

Tags: 14.04, unity, 16.04, desktop-environments, .desktop

Sometimes, lately very often when I try to click around window header or try to drag and drop it, it simply doesn't register my clicks. It feels like I am clicking void background.

This issue first happened to me when I first time installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I fixed it by using this command:

```
unity --replace
```

However, on my just installed Ubuntu 16.04 this issue returned.

The `unity --replace` command fixes it for a moment, until I move to next window, then I need to run it again. I even put it on shortcut because it happens every few seconds.

About hardware:

Razer Naga Molten and Wireless logitech mouse.

However I had this issue even before I even started using this wireless logitech mouse.

I am using AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 955 Processor x4. Gallium 0.4 on AMD CAYMAN (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0) graphics and 64-bit OS type.

```
kunok@private:~$ lspci | grep VGA
```

> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
>   [AMD/ATI] Cayman PRO [Radeon HD 6950]

I noticed **it actually clicks whatever is behind current window**.

It also happens on Gnome Shell 3 desktop env. as well as on xubuntu and xfce environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Workaround:**

I tried almost all desktop environments and [KDE Plasma](https://www.kde.org/workspaces/plasmadesktop/) was the one that finally worked properly. No more click/focus problems.

Ps. this desktop GUI feels really nice.